# Why didn't the pronunciation of "boor" change in a similar way to "poor"?

Tags: pronunciation, historical-change, vowels

I have a South African colleague who pronounces "poor" as ***pooeur*** and I find it fairly humorous given I never hear it pronounced that way. Of course, ***pooeur***, at some stage, would have been the general pronunciation of *poor*. This colleague also recently pronounced "boor" as ***booeur***. Again, this stood out for its difference to what I would normally hear.

For curiosity's sake, I decided to check a range of online **British English** dictionaries (since they are the de facto standard for Australian English) to compare the pronunciation of "poor" and "boor" and what I found was quite surprising.

Despite *por* being listed as the general pronunciation of "poor" in (most of) the dictionaries, *booeur* was preferred over *bor* for "boor" (and usually also the only listed British pronunciation).

### Pronunciation of "poor", according to the dictionaries

- *Cambridge Dictionaries Online*: /pɔːr/
- *Collins*: /pʊə/, /pɔː/
- *Macmillan*: /pɔː(r)/, /pʊə(r)/
- *Oxford Dictionaries* and the *OED*: /pɔː/, /pʊə/
- *Macquarie (Aus)*: /pɔ/

### Pronunciation of "boor"

- *Cambridge Dictionaries Online:* /bʊər/
- *Collins:* /bʊə/
- *Macmillan:* /bʊə(r)/
- *Oxford Dictionaries* and *OED*: /bɔː/, /bʊə/
- *Macquarie (Aus):* /bɔ/, /bʊə/

### Questions

This, then, makes me wonder:

- Why has the pronunciation of "poor" changed more than that of "boor"? Does it come down to word frequency?
- Do these pronunciations accurately reflect how the word is generally pronounced by the general population, British or otherwise?

Comment: ... or maybe the pronunciation of both words is currently changing, and the dictionaries just update more frequently used words more often. Anyway, reports are that the vowel in *poor, boor, cure, pure, sure, moor* is quickly dying in England. See [this blog entry.](http://englishspeechservices.com/blog/the-demise-of-%CA%8A%C9%99-as-in-cure/) I believe it's still thriving in California.

Comment: And to build on what @PeterShor says, it may be a difference in rate of change based on usage: *poor* is used [much more often](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=poor%2Cboor&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpoor%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cboor%3B%2Cc0) than *boor* and might be expected thereby to undergo change more rapidly.

Comment: I don't understand the queation: those two are perfect rhymes for me.

Comment: As a Californian I have to ask, how the heck does *cure* rhyme with *poor*?

Comment: @ThePhoton It doesn't. I say *por* and *kyoo-er*; some people might say *pooeur* (a bit like "poo" and "err") and *kyor*.

Comment: If I understood it correctly, the article Peter linked says that they rhyme for some people.

Comment: @ThePhoton Oops, sorry. I thought you were referring to the question and interpreted the phonetic spelling differently to me.

Comment: @ThePhoton: Which of the following does *Coors* (as in beer) have the same vowel as: *pure, poor, skewer, more, tour, lure*. When I lived in California several decades ago, I think it was rare to pronounce it any other way than /kʊrz/, and I don't think the *pure/poor* split had reached it yet. Obviously times have changed.

Comment: @PeterShor, for me, *pure* and *cure* just about rhyme with *fewer*; *poor* rhymes with *bore*, and *Coors* is usually the same as *cores* (but I could also imagine it closer to the end of *endures*)

Comment: @The Photon: The vowels in *pure, poor, tour, lure, sure* all used to be the same (probably partway between the two vowels you use). But now, for many Americans, these words are split into two or three different vowels (those in *more, fur, skewer*). This is the *pure-poor* split. Many people still use the original vowel in these words, and you can hear what it sounded like in [dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tour) [pronunciations](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lure)—although some of the dictionary pronouncers have the *pure-poor* split, not all of them do.

Comment: @ThePhoton Something similar, but different in the details, happened in England, where it seems to be considerably farther along. This is what the OP is asking about.

Comment: A 'bore' and a 'boor' are indistinguishable if the latter can't be relied upon to be consistently pronounced with /ʊə/.

I'm a BrE speaker without a strong /ʊə/, but I would still say 'poor' and 'boor' differently to my own ear I think. Not sure of the IPA, but it's clearer I think if you imagine saying 'boorish' and 'poorish'.

Answer (score 2):

It might be due to frequency. I don't think this is very easily explainable, but maybe someone will find a study on it that will prove me wrong. I would say it is just an irregular split that some people have (other people pronounce both words so that they rhyme).

In general, rhotic vowels in English often develop inconsistently in some words. Some examples: most American English speakers pronounce "squirrel" and "mirror" with different vowels; many British English speakers pronounce "clerk" and "jerk" with different vowels, and nearly all speakers pronounce "spear" and "bear" with different vowels.

Words that in older stages of the language had /oːr/ or /uːr/ have often developed to have /ɔ(ː)(r)/ in modern English accents. (In some accents, like mine, this vowel has shifted to /ɜr/ rather than /ɔr/ in some contexts, mainly in situations where it was originally preceded by /j/; e.g. the word "surely" may be pronounced the same as "Shirley" or "shorely" depending on the accent, or kept distinct from both.) Other examples are *floor, door* (universally pronounced with the NORTH/FORCE vowel, as far as  I know), *whore* (only pronounced with /ʊə(r)/ dialectally), and *moor, tour* (generally /ʊə(r)/ in accents that have this sound, but may be NORTH/FORCE in other accents, such as mine, that don't have /ʊə(r)/ at all).

My impression is that for some words, such as *[door](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/14522/5581),* it's unclear whether the current pronunciation is the result of lowering or of a lack of Great-Vowel-Shift raising.

Some accents have disyllabic /u(ː).ɚ/ as a possibility in some of these words.

I'm not at all sure about what I say in the following paragraph, but I would guess that another factor influencing the pronunciatiom of "boor" might be a desire to keep it aurally distinct from the word "bore". It's true that "poor" also has homophones, but I think it is much easier to confuse things like "What a bore!"/"What a boor!" than it is to confuse things like "Poor me!"/"Pour me!"/"Pore me!"

Comment: So what vowel do you use in *lure*? Neither /ɔr/ nor /ɜr/ sounds right to me in that word, and I've been wondering for quite a while which vowel people who don't have /ʊr/ use for it.

Comment: @PeterShor: The vowel I naturally use in "lure" is /ɜr/. I do currently have /uɚ/ as a possible variant in this word and some others, but that's the result of a conscious adjustment.